# ubuntu 20.04 "unable to find a medium containing a live file system" while booting from USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, usb

I have tried:
Multiple bootable USB creators (Rufus, BalenaEchter, Easy2boot,)

Different USB sticks

Different Linux distros Manjaro and Pop-OS (Manjaro Didn't load the desktop and Pop-OS had the same error as ubuntu)

The USB stick booted up in a different computer perfectly

Specs:

Ryzen 5 2400g

Nvidia GTX 1060 6gb

16gb RAM

Asus ROG Strix B350F Gaming MOBO

I have looked at other similar questions and I can't find a solution that works for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer won't boot from a USB with ubuntu 20.04 on it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251395/my-computer-wont-boot-from-a-usb-with-ubuntu-20-04-on-it)

Comment: don't open duplicate questions, rather edit the question if you want to clearify things ;)

Comment: “*unable to find a medium containing a live file system*” usually means that you forgot (or failed) to tell your system BIOS to boot from the USB. Try a different USB port and try changing your BIOS settings.

Comment: I fixed it by updated my BIOS!